# Zipping 2 arrays in ruby in random locations

Tags: ruby, arrays, merge

Is there an easy way to zip 2 arrays in random locations and **keep their original order**?

for example

```
a=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]


b=["one","two","three","four"]
```

and a random number from 0 to 5 with `rand(5)`

```
zipped = [0,"one",1,2,3,"two",4,"three",5,6,7,8,"four",9,10]
```

and the random series would be `1,3,1,4` as location to where to "zip" each element of b into a

The best I could do is

```
i=0
merged=a
b.each do |x|
rnd = rand(5)
merged.insert(i+rnd,x)
i=i+rnd
end
```

Comment: Well, this edit changes everything

Comment: I bet I saw an answer from somebody and just corrected it a bit: `a.zip((b + [nil] * (a.size - b.size)).shuffle).flatten.compact`

Comment: More answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14713338/316700

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This version will give a balanced shuffling, with insertions not biased to either end of the array.

```
def ordered_random_merge(a,b)
  a, b = a.dup, b.dup
  a.map{rand(b.size+1)}.sort.reverse.each do |index|
    b.insert(index, a.pop)
  end
  b
end
```

Comment: this is a good fair solution, but you've swapped which of a,b is the merged target from OPs original question.

Comment: huh? This returns a new array, leaving the old ones untouched. The results are identical whether `a` is merged into `b`, or the other way around. I actually tested it to make sure, since my first version (unposted) always merged the smaller into the larger.

Comment: That is, the *effect* is identical, not the random results :) It would be impossible to tell the difference between a set of results from `a` being merged into `b`, and a set of `b` into `a`. It is a commutative operation.

Comment: heh. Right you are!  I didn't think it through.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a variant of [Mark Hubbart's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14378016/1074296) in a more functional style.

MergeTuple = Struct.new :place, :value

```
def ordered_random_merge( merge_to, merge_from )
  merge_from.
  map { |e| MergeTuple[ rand( merge_to.size+1 ), e ] }.
  sort_by { |mt| - mt.place }.
  each_with_object( merge_to.dup ) { |mt, merged| merged.insert(mt.place, mt.value) }
end
```