# Ruby, how to shuffle one array into another

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

Two arrays:

```
a1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
a2 = [1, 2, 3]
```

How to insert `a2` into `a1`, keeping the *a2 order* but in **random indexes** of *a1*?

Comment: This is not something every ruby user will need. So, what have you tried?

Comment: So you'd want this sort of thing as your result: %w(a b 1 c 2 d e f 3)?  But not: %w(3 a b 1 2 c d e f).  Is that right?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I think, shuffling one array into another can be a very common need, maybe not as common as the normal `Array#shuffle` method but still useful.

Comment: @DaveSteinberg yes, is like the two arrays are two card decks, and you insert one into the other, like in a pocker game when you try to mess the cards.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Zipping 2 arrays in ruby in random locations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376902/zipping-2-arrays-in-ruby-in-random-locations)

Comment: @sawa you're right.. making a cross link in the other question too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(0..a1.length).to_a.sample(a2.length).sort
.zip(a2)
.reverse
.each{|i, e| a1.insert(i, e)}
```

Comment: +1 Computationally not the most efficient, but modular and simple. Also it keeps the imperative updates at a minimum, which is always good (weird layout, though)

Comment: +1, works in my tests but you should clarify that, at the end, the real result is into the `a1` array and not in the returned value for the sentence.

Comment: Even if I like more the verbosity style of the [@nicooga's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14714379/316700) I accept this based in popularity.

Answer (score 6):

Here's my updated answer:

```
a1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
a2 = [1,2,3]

# scales to N arrays by just adding to this hash
h = { :a1 => a1.dup, :a2 => a2.dup }
# => {:a1=>["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"], :a2=>[1, 2, 3]}

# Create an array of size a1+a2 with elements representing which array to pull from
sources = h.inject([]) { |s,(k,v)| s += [k] * v.size }
# => [:a1, :a1, :a1, :a1, :a1, :a1, :a2, :a2, :a2]

# Pull from the array indicated by the hash after shuffling the source list
sources.shuffle.map { |a| h[a].shift }
# => ["a", "b", 1, "c", 2, "d", "e", 3, "f"]
```

Credit for the algorithm goes to my colleague Ryan.

OLD ANSWER DOES NOT PRESERVE ORDER OF BOTH

```
a1.inject(a2) { |s,i| s.insert(rand(s.size), i) }
```

Using a2 as a destination, insert into a2 each value from a1 at a random offset of a2.

Comment: Note that this modifies a2, which may/may not be desired.  Nice solution.

Comment: I don't think this will give equal distribution among the positions.

Comment: So you don't need to preserve a1's order?

Comment: Should that not be `rand(s.size+1)`? Now the last value is always 3.

Comment: Just to be accurate with the question: the order of the _randomly inserted_ array has to be **preserved**.

Comment: Sorry, misinterpreted the requirements. I'll see about improving my answer. And @steenslag, you are correct.

Answer (score 3):

Maintains order of both arrays by simulating a realistic shuffle, once an element of an array is inserted into the other array the next element cannot be place before it.

```
class Array
  def shuffle_into(array)
    n = 0
    self.each.with_object(array.dup) do |e, obj|
      i = rand(n..obj.size)
      obj.insert(i, e)
      n = i + 1
    end
  end
end
```

Might be able to clean up the `n = 0` floating around.

Example: `a2.shuffle_into(a1) => [1, "a", "b", "c", "d", 2, "e", "f", 3]`

Answer (score 2):

This ugly piece of crap does the job (without messing with any of the arrays order):

```
class Array
  def shuffle_into(ary)
    a1 = ary.dup
    a2 = dup
    Array.new(a1.size + a2.size) do
      [true, false].sample ? (a1.shift || a2.shift) : (a2.shift || a1.shift)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: +1 works in my tests, and I like the visibility of the logic.

Comment: I like the idea, maybe you can edit your answer and make the code shorter: https://gist.github.com/fguillen/4721938

Answer (score -1):

`a1.zip((a2 + [nil] * (a1.size - a2.size)).shuffle).flatten.compact`

BTW, possible dup: [Zipping 2 arrays in ruby in random locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376902/zipping-2-arrays-in-ruby-in-random-locations#comment19995708_14376902)

Comment: I have duplications `["d", 1, "a", 2, "e", "d", "f", "a", "f", "b", "e", "c", "b", 3, "c"]`. And we can't use `uniq` in the exit because we don't know if the duplications were already in the original arrays